# what if when two UITableView in one ViewController and one with custom cell refrence and another is a simple

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i'm trying to use two UITableView in one ViewController. one UITableView with the reference of custom cell and the other one is simple...I've written this code but it gives me error of control may reach end of non-void function...

so give me the suggestion for it...what can i do...?

thanks in advance...

here, is my code...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (tableView==self.categoryTable)
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (nil == cell1)
        {
            cell1 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        cell1.textLabel.text=[category objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell1.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];

         return cell1;
    }
    else if (tableView==self.listTable)
    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
        RWTListCell *cell2 = (RWTListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell2 == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell2 = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        //NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexxxx);
        //NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)imagesmarry.count );

        cell2.textLabel.text=[[imagesmarry_pictitle objectAtIndex:indexxxx]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //NSLog(@"%@",[imagesmarry_pictitle objectAtIndex:indexxxx]);

       return cell2;
    }

}
```

Comment: use if-else instead of else if

Comment: you are not returning the cell. Thats the problem..

Comment: Did you find relative answer as you required?  If yes, then upvote and accept the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, you have to init the type the cell as UITableviewViewCell  and cast after. Tell me if this sample answer to your question.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {  
    UITableViewCell *cell;
     if (tableView==self.categoryTable) {

         static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
         cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

         if (nil == cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
         }

         cell.textLabel.text=[category objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];



     } else if (tableView==self.listTable) {

         static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
         cell = (RWTListCell *)[tableView      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

         if (cell == nil) {
              NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
              cell = (RWTListCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
         }


         //NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexxxx);
         //NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)imagesmarry.count );

         ((RWTListCell *) cell).textLabel.text=[[imagesmarry_pictitle objectAtIndex:indexxxx]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //NSLog(@"%@",[imagesmarry_pictitle objectAtIndex:indexxxx]);
}

 return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can lose the second `if` condition

```
if (tableView==self.categoryTable)
{
//do stuff
 return cell1;
}

else
{
//do stuff
 return cell2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell;
if (tableView==self.categoryTable)
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (nil == cell1)
    {
        cell1 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell1.textLabel.text=[category objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell1.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];

    cell=cell1;
}
else if (tableView==self.listTable)
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
    RWTListCell *cell2 = (RWTListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell2 == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell2 = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    //NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexxxx);
    //NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)imagesmarry.count );

    cell2.textLabel.text=[[imagesmarry_pictitle objectAtIndex:indexxxx]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSLog(@"%@",[imagesmarry_pictitle objectAtIndex:indexxxx]);

   cell=cell2;
}
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

  if (tableView==self.categoryTable) {
   ...
   ...
   return cell1;
  }
  else if (tableView==self.listTable) {
   ...
   ...
   return cell2;
  }

 retrun cell;
}
```

Try this, take a dummy cell and return it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just add return; at the last.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if (condition 1) {
      // statements
       return cellType_1;
   } else if (condition 2) {
      //statements
      return cellType_2;
   }

   return;
}
```

or you can also do this -

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (condition 1) {
      // statements
      return cellType_1;
   } else {
      //statements
      return cellType_2;
   }
}
```

remove the second condition . because you must return in non void method weather your all condition is true or not.

Comment: Your first block of code needs to return something.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your problem is not returning any cell to `tableview`.

I have altered your code. I just removed your `else if` condition

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (tableView==self.categoryTable)
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (nil == cell1)
    {
        cell1 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell1.textLabel.text=[category objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell1.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];

     return cell1;
}

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
    RWTListCell *cell2 = (RWTListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell2 == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell2 = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    //NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexxxx);
    //NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)imagesmarry.count );

    cell2.textLabel.text=[[imagesmarry_pictitle objectAtIndex:indexxxx]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSLog(@"%@",[imagesmarry_pictitle objectAtIndex:indexxxx]);

   return cell2;

}
```